# Using filename prefix as custom key value in Cloud Storage Notification for Pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

We have files, containing replicated data from database, generated constantly (by a DB data replication tool called HVR). The format of the generated files is `<timestamp>-<tablename>.avro`, and these are dumped continuously to a GCS bucket. We want to create a Storage Notification going to a Pubsub topic where the ordering key metadata is `<timestamp-prefix-of-the-filename>`, which in turn will be used by some subscription/s to determine the ordering. The `<timestamp>` is the first 17 characters of the filename, or at least the set of characters before the first dash "-". How do we generate such Storage Notification with custom keys?

Comment: What do you expect with the ordering key? To deliver the file day by day, and until a day is not completed, no further days are delivered, right?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere These data files are not guaranteed to be generated by the HVR replication agent in order and/or not guaranteed to be written in the Cloud Storage in order. The timestamp part in the filename guarantees the order they are captured from the source database. The delivery is not per day, but from few seconds to few minutes apart.

Comment: could you confirm if your requirement is >>Pubsub topic should receive object name as timestamp-filename format? and are you implementing [Pub/Sub notifications for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Yes, generated GCS objects have timestamp-filename format. Yes, also in Pub/Sub notification for GCS.